How to prefix automatically language in path of route with Angular 14
I try to add the language of customer directly in the path like
/en/dashboard

And if a customer go to the web site with an older link, like
/home

I want to add automatically the default language in the url like /en/home
This is my routes :
{
  path: ":lang",
  resolve: {
    language: isValidLanguage
  },
  children: [
    {
      path: "dashboard",
      component: Dashboard
    },
    {
      path: "home",
      component: Home
    },
    {
      path: "**",
      redirectTo: "/en/dashboard",
      pathMatch: "prefix"
    }
  ]
}

Actually my router redirect the older urls to /en/dashboard

My solution involves using canActivate to redirect the user to the desired route based on the language set.
You have to define the valid languages on the can activate so that it checks for invalid routes.
  canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): any {
    const validLangs = ['en'];
    console.log(route, state);
    if (!validLangs.some((lang: string) => state.url.includes(lang))) {
      return this.router.createUrlTree(['en', ...state.url.split('/').filter(x => x)]);
    }
    return true;
  }
}

Full Code:
import {
  Routes,
  ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
  RouterStateSnapshot,
  CanActivate,
  Router,
} from '@angular/router';
import { ExampleComponent } from './example/example.component';
import { HelloComponent, EmptyComponent } from './hello.component';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class CanActivateTeam implements CanActivate {
  constructor(private router: Router) {}

  canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): any {
    const validLangs = ['en'];
    console.log(route, state);
    if (!validLangs.some((lang: string) => state.url.includes(lang))) {
      return this.router.createUrlTree([
        'en',
        ...state.url.split('/').filter((x) => x),
      ]);
    }
    return true;
  }
}

export const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: ':lang',
    children: [
      {
        path: 'dashboard',
        component: ExampleComponent,
      },
      {
        path: 'home',
        component: HelloComponent,
      },
      {
        path: '**',
        component: EmptyComponent,
        canActivate: [CanActivateTeam],
      },
    ],
  },
];

Stackblitz Demo

redirectTo can also be a function with custom logic, which seems to be necessary in your case:
{
  path: "**",
  redirectTo: ({ url }) => `/en/${url}`,
  pathMatch: "prefix"
}

Note that this feature was added with Angular v18, in older Angular versions you cannot use this approach.

I am using angular 14 I think it's not possible. I have this error ({ url }: { url: string; }) => string' is not assignable to type 'string'.

@R3tep this feature is not available in Angular 14, one more reason to upgrade (besides compatibility, security, performance, DX, ...)

Thanks for your help, this way is nice I will use it soon
